# Is it possible to break a long line into multiple lines along method call boundaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

From multiple method calls:

```
result=long_name.long_name2(a,b,c,d,e,f,g).long_name3(h,i,j,k,l,m)
```

To something along the lines of:

```
result=long_name.
    long_name2(a,b,c,d,e,f,g).
    long_name3(h,i,j,k,l,m)
```

The backslash `\` line continuation character does not seem to work for this purpose. E.g.:

```
# Not valid code
result=long_name.\
    long_name2(a,b,c,d,e,f,g).\
    long_name3(h,i,j,k,l,m)
```

Comment: would storing temporary variables not be an option?

Comment: Backslash continuation should work fine. You probably had something after a backslash on the same line. (Spaces and comments count.)